# How to get data from a form and post it into iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

So I have a **form**...

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Post a comment:</legend>
<form target="forum" method="post" action="forum.**SomeKindOfExtension**" >
                Name: <br />
        <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
                Subject:<br />
        <input type="text" name="subject" size="50"/><br />
                Comment:<br />
<textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="100">Hello,</textarea><br />

<input type="submit" value="Send" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Then I want to **take the data** (name, subject and comment) and **put that into an iframe**...

```
<iframe name="forum" src="forum.**SomeKindOfExtension**" 
width="900" height="500" ></iframe>
```

Hopefully you can see my problem, which is **what type of file** will **read the form data** and **display it in the iframe window**? When I've been looking up answers people seem to be using javascript or php but I can't seem to make any of the code work for me.

So if anyone could help me here that would be much appreciated.

Comment: People ARE using Javascript for this. Using PHP would mean submitting the form to a server, which would refresh the entire page, not just an iframe.

Comment: Is your Iframe on the same page? And how do you want to read the data? On a button click or as the user types into the textbox?

Comment: @Searock the iframe is on the same page and I want the data to be read into the iframe on a button click:

<input type="submit" value="Send" />

Comment: @Searoc, display it how? as text, as a input?

Comment: @david How do I know? :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a iframe on the same page would make no sense because when you click on the submit button the whole page will be submitted to a different page specified it the action attribute of the form.

Instead you could use a different button (not the submit button) to send data to the iframe or use a parent page and then include your two frames ie the form and the iframe.

Here's the first example

**mainpage.html**

```
<HTML>
     <HEAD>
          <TITLE>JavaScript Example</TITLE>
     </HEAD>

     <BODY>

          <iframe src="frame.html" width="100%" height="100%" name="someFrame"></iframe>

          <FORM name="form1">
               <INPUT type="button" value="Click Me" 
               onClick="someFrame.document.form1.text1.value='Me!'">
          </FORM>
     </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**frame.html**

```
<HTML>
     <HEAD>
          <TITLE>JavaScript Example</TITLE>
     </HEAD>

     <BODY>
          <FORM name="form1">
               <INPUT type="text" name="text1" size="25" value="">
          </FORM>
      </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here's the second example

**parent.html**

```
<HTML>
     <HEAD>
          <TITLE>JavaScript Example</TITLE>
     </HEAD>

     <FRAMESET cols="80%,20%">
          <FRAME SRC="left.html" name="left_frame">
          <FRAME SRC="right.html" name="right_frame">
     </FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

**left.html**

```
<HTML>
     <HEAD>
          <TITLE>JavaScript Example</TITLE>
     </HEAD>

     <BODY>
          <FORM>
               <INPUT type="button" value="Click ME" 
               onClick="parent.right_frame.document.form1.text1.value='Me!'">
          </FORM>
     </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**right.html**

```
<HTML>
     <HEAD>
          <TITLE>JavaScript Example</TITLE>
     </HEAD>

     <BODY>
          <FORM name="form1">
               <INPUT type="text" name="text1" size="25" value="">
          </FORM>
      </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: The OP is asking about the backend service or api which will accept the form data and respond with something.